# Nexus S doesn't start up

Tags: samsung-nexus-s

I flashed my Nexus S with the 4.1.2 factory image this morning and then relocked the bootloader. Everything was going fine, until I turned it off (it charges faster this way) and it wouldn't turn on again. The battery started getting warmer and the phone doesn't respond at all.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you tell after how much time battery starts to warm? Or getting hot

Comment: I would suggest you to flash 4.4.3 and then lock.

Comment: I'm unable to physically turn the phone on - no fastboot, no download mode. The battery starts to get warm as soon as its plugged in. My computer doesn't detect the device. The phone was at 30% battery when I powered it off.

Comment: Seems voltage issue. Your battery is not supplying voltage as intended. I would suggest you get a replacement. You will get warranty since you said you relocked the device. Good luck, and don't worry you can easily get replacement 

Comment: tried another battery, same behaviour, seems like the phone processor can't even boot the hardcoded charging code to charge the battery?

Comment: Still I would advice going for a repair since a phone should not give such issues in flashing rom